# How do I get the DailyMotion Video Id from the URL IOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, dailymotion-api

http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x3vfu7n_kashif-abbasi-take-class-of-zaeem-qadri_news
I need to get the video id from dailymotion url. I need regular expression for that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below regular expression:

```
    NSString *strRegExp=@"/video/([^_]+)/";

    NSError *regexError = nil;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:strRegExp options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&regexError];

    if (regexError) {
        NSLog(@"regexError: %@", regexError);

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, its not working I'm able to get video/x3vfu7n using this NSString *regexString = @"video/([^_]+)"

Comment: Now get last string value separated by '/', it will be your video id@user2964134

Comment: Happy to help!@user2964134